# How do I load related entities of type IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm trying to load related entities of a SingleOrDefault entity, but I am getting the following exception:

The navigation property of type IEnumerable is not a single implementation of type ICollection

I've tried doing this several ways and ultimately get the same error above for each query against the context (I've included the other ways in comments).

```
using(var context = CustomObjectContextCreator.Create())
        {
            return  context.Job.Include("Surveys").Include("SiteInfoes")
        .Where(r => r.Jobid == jobId).SingleOrDefault();

            //context.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            //var Job = context.Job.Where(r => r.Jobid == jobId).SingleOrDefault();
            //context.LoadProperty(Job, "Surveys");
            //context.LoadProperty(Job, "SiteInfoes");

            //var Job = (from j in context.Job
            //                   .Include("Surveys")
            //                   .Include("SiteInfoes")
            //               select j).SingleOrDefault();

            //var Job = context.Job.Where(r => r.Jobid == jobId).SingleOrDefault();
            //var surveys = context.Surveys.Where(s => s.JobID == jobId);
            //var wellInfoes = context.SiteInfoes.Where(w => w.Jobid == jobId);
            //Job.Surveys = surveys.ToList();
            //Job.SiteInfoes = wellInfoes.ToList();

            //return Job;
        }
```

Here are the POCO objects I'm using:

```
    public class Job
    {
        public int? Jobid { get; set; }
        public string JobLocation { get; set; }
        public string JobName { get; set; }
        public virtual IEnumerable<Survey> Surveys { get; set; }
        public virtual IEnumerable<SiteInfo> SiteInfoes { get; set; }
    }

public class Survey
    {
        public int SurveyID { get; set; }
        public int? JobID { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateTime { get; set; }
        public string Report { get; set; }
        public virtual Job Job { get; set; }
    }

public class SiteInfo
    {
      public int Jobid { get; set; }
      public string SiteLocation { get; set; }
      public virtual JobInfo JobInfo { get; set; }
    }
```

How do I properly load the related entities?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`IEnumerable<T>` is not supported as a type for a navigation collection. You must use `ICollection<T>` or another interface derived from it (for example `IList<T>`) or a concrete implementation of `ICollection<T>` - like `List<T>`, `HashSet<T>`, etc.

Comment: it sounds like that's what the exception was telling me.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Can you please explain WHY IEnumerable<T> is not supported? - I'd dearly like to know.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you need ICollection instead of IEnumerable.