# Why does EF not support projections to types implementing IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ienumerable, dbcontext

It is easy to map an entity to unonymous type or to the type with parameterless constructor:

```
context.EntitiesSet.Select( entity => new MyClass { Prop = entity.Id } );
```

But if `MyClass` implements `IEnumerable` interface then EF throws `NotSupportedException`.

I'd like to know what's the point for this oddity.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is related to this question: [How do I load related entities of type IEnumerable<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7940130/how-do-i-load-related-entities-of-type-ienumerablet), where it is asked why *navigation* properties can't implement `IEnumerable`.

In the current EF 6 source there is a check whether a type is supported for materialization. There it only says in a comment

> // types implementing IEnumerable are not supported

Not much of an explanation there.

However, for collection properties I can see why it makes sense to require at least `ICollection`s, because it is essential that object can be added and removed from collections (`IEnumerable` has no `Add` and `Delete` methods).

I think that the case of a projected type implementing `IEnumerable` was either deemed too uncommon to support or just overlooked.