# EF loading related data issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've two entities:

```
public class Album
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual int GenreId { get; set; }
    public virtual int ArtistId { get; set; }
    public virtual string CoverURL { get; set; }
    public virtual int Cost { get; set; }
    public virtual Artist Artist { get; set; }
    public virtual Genre Genre { get; set; }
}

public class Genre
{
    public int Id { get; set; }       
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Album> Albums{get;set;}
    public int AlbumCount { get { return Albums.Count(); } }
    public Genre()
    {
        Albums = new List<Album>();
    }
}
```

and here is the controller action.

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var genres = db.Genres.ToList();
        return View(genres);
    }
```

I've one to many mapping between Genre and Album( A album can have only one genre, but a genre can belong to multiple albums). When i try to fetch Album details(including genre nav. property) it gives me expected data. But when i try to display all genres it always gives me 0 as album count. I suspect a binding issue, but i'm unable to find out where. Would be glad if you can help find out the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use `ICollection` instead of `IEnumerable` for your navigation properties :

```
public virtual ICollection<Album> Albums { get; set; }
```

(See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7940130/how-do-i-load-related-entities-of-type-ienumerablet) for example)

Then you can use the `Include` method to fetch `Albums` with `Genres` :

```
db.Genres.Include(genre => genre.Albums)
```

or

```
db.Genres.Include("Albums")
```

EDIT : read this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113244/why-use-icollection-and-not-ienumerable-or-listt-on-many-many-one-many-relatio) for more informations about collection types. Basically, `ICollection` inherits from `IEnumerable`, and allows you to modify your collection (`IEnumerable`'s main purpose is iteration).

Comment: Thanks. This works. I'm new to MVC & EF. Could you please throw some light on ICollection and IEnumerable?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var genres = db.Genres.Include(x => x.Albums).ToList();
    return View(genres);
}
```

Comment: Yup tried this. But it gives me syntax error. Possibly the EF framework I'm using doesn't support this. It expects a "string path" as argument.

Comment: Have you tried with a string? Like this: var genres = db.Genres.Include("Albums").ToList();

Comment: A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'MvcMusicStore.DAL.Genre' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'Albums'. This error comes.

Comment: Have you configured your modelbuilder correct? Something like this: modelBuilder.Entity<Genres>()
    .HasMany(x => x.Albums) Read more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx

Comment: No I've not configured. Is it necessary?