# Entity Framework Core always returns an empty list of foreign rows

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm working with Entity Framework Core and ASP.NET Core 3.1.

I have two simple models:

```cs
public class UserModel 
{
        public int    UserModelId   { get; set; }
        public string Email         { get; set; }
        public string Password      { get; set; }
        public string Name          { get; set; }
        public string Surname       { get; set; }
        public string Token         { get; set; }

        public List<TherapyModel> Therapies { get; set; }
}

public class TherapyModel 
{
        public int      TherapyModelId  { get; set; }
        public int      UserModelId     { get; set; }
        public string   Title           { get; set; }
        public int      Quantity        { get; set; }
        public bool     Monday          { get; set; }
        public bool     Tuesday         { get; set; }
        public bool     Wednesday       { get; set; }
        public bool     Thursday        { get; set; }
        public bool     Friday          { get; set; }
        public bool     Saturday        { get; set; }
        public bool     Sunday          { get; set; }
        public string   ImgBase64       { get; set; }
        public string   ImgUrl          { get; set; }

        public int UserModelForeignKey { get; set; }
        public UserModel UserModel           { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I initialize everything in this way:

```cs
public class DatabaseManager : DbContext 
{
        //Entities:
        public DbSet<UserModel>     UserModel    { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TherapyModel>  TherapyModel { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating( ModelBuilder modelBuilder ) 
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<TherapyModel>().HasOne(p => p.UserModel)
                                               .WithMany(s => s.Therapies)
                                               .HasForeignKey(p => p.UserModelForeignKey);
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
            => optionsBuilder.UseMySql( @"Server=127.0.0.1;database=test2;uid=root;pwd=" ); );
}
```

The local db is populated correctly, with the right foreign keys. In fact this query returns 3 rows:

```sql
select * 
from usermodel 
join therapymodel on therapymodel.UserModelForeignKey
```

But, for some reason, when I try to get the `UserModel` from my C# code, this always returns "Therapies" as NULL. I get to takes `UserModel` in this two way:

```cs
UserModel user = dbManager.UserModel.FirstOrDefault( user => user.UserModelId == iUserModel.UserModelId );

var users = dbManager.UserModel;
```

Both user and users had Therapies as NULL. I really can't understand why. Any help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EF loading related data issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20838822/ef-loading-related-data-issue)

Comment: Two comments, not directly related to your question: better to name your entities in the DbContext class as plural (UserModels and TherapyModels) and there is no need to have that code in OnModelCreating, EF Core should be able to infer that from your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found finally an answer. By reading this post:

https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/lazy-loading

I enabled Lazy-Loading ( is enabled by default ) but the foreign key **must be virtual**:

```cs
public class Author
{
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Book> Books { get; set; } = new List<Book>();
}
public class Book
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public virtual Author Author { get; set; }
}
```

Now it works, the Microsoft Tutorial don't tell you nothing about the Lazy Loading and the fact to declare the foreign key as virtual. I hope this could be help anyone in future.

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is old, but I ran into similar problems and found that dropping the two-directional Model relation was the cleanest solution for me.

So here's my solution for those who feel the many to one reference is superfluous:

```
public class UserModel 
{
    // ...
    public List<TherapyModel> Therapies { get; set; } = new List<TherapyModel>();
}

public class TherapyModel 
{
    // ...
    public int UserModelForeignKey { get; set; }
    // I Dropped the UserModel here [public UserModel UserModel { get; set; }]
}

// ... Note OnModelCreating : HasOne(p => p.UserModel) => HasOne<UserModel>()

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
{
    modelBuilder
        .Entity<TherapyModel>()
        .HasOne<UserModel>()
        .WithMany(user => user.Therapies)
        .HasForeignKey(thp => thp.UserModelForeignKey);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to eager load the `Therapies`, like this:

```
UserModel user = dbManager.UserModel.Where( user => user.UserModelId == iUserModel.UserModelId ).Include( user => user.Therapies ).SingleOrDefault();
```

Using `SingleOrDefault` because, as you are querying per primary key, there should be really at most only one record.
See more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data.