# How to include related table in LINQ query?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-entities

I have two classes, **Company** and **CompanyAddress**.

For every **Company** there can be multiple **CompanyAddresses**, such as Invoice address and correspondence address.

Via entity framework, I'm trying to include all **CompanyAddresses** that belong the **Company**. However, I keep getting the following debug error:

*An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'StatelyTechAdmin.Models.Company' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'CompanyAddresses'.*

Can anyone advise me on why I cannot include all addresses in my LINQ query? Please note I am very new to Entity Framework.

**Company Class**

```
public class Company
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public virtual long CompanyId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Company Name")]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<CompanyAddress> CompanyAddresses { get; set; }
}
```

**CompanyAddress Class**

```
public class CompanyAddress
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public virtual long CompanyAddressId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual long CompanyId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CompanyId")]
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual int CompanyAddressTypeId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CompanyAddressTypeId")]
    public virtual CompanyAddressType CompanyAddressType { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Address 1")]
    public virtual string Address1 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Address 2")]
    public virtual string Address2 {get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Town")]
    public virtual string Town { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "City")]
    public virtual string City { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual long CountyId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CountyId")]
    [Display(Name = "County")]
    public virtual County County { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Postal Code")]
    public virtual string PostalCode { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

**Calling Method from MVC Action**

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var comp = db.Companies.Include(a => a.CompanyAddresses).ToList();

        return View(comp);
    }
```

All advice welcome! Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use IEnumerable for your navigation property. You need to use ICollection or a type derived from it.

[How do I load related entities of type IEnumerable<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7940130/how-do-i-load-related-entities-of-type-ienumerablet)